# Magento is slower with redis on docker

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, redis, docker

I just switched from cache in files to redis, and according to benchmark, my store is about 10 % slower. This is my config:

```
<cache>
    <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
    <backend_options>
        <server>redis</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
        <port>6379</port>
        <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
        <database>0</database>
        <password></password>
        <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
        <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
        <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
        <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
        <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
        <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
        <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
    </backend_options>
</cache>
```

I'm using docker with redis as linked container. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the env.php you mention "redis" as the cacheing server (well, docker). Where exactly is located that container? Is it local lan, wan, public cloud,etc? Many times, pushing cache via "Ethernet" and not socket (locally) means that a slow network or a laggy connection can double or even triple the time it need to comunicate with your magento, since eth connection is round trip and mainly TCP means that packages need to be verified back and forth. You can use this setup ad testing but for production i suggest socket redis connection on the same docker (pretty unusual although) or ask your provider to place the "redis" docker as close as possible to your php/magento container

Comment: Redis containter is on the same machine as PHP, nginx and mysql.